# Loop down non empty rows and pass row number to function

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA which converts cells to JSON:

```
' Convert JSON
Public Sub exceltojson()

Dim rng As Range, items As New Collection, myitem As New Dictionary, i As Integer, cell As Variant
Set rng = Range("A2")
i = 0

For Each cell In rng
    Debug.Print (cell.Value)
    myitem("name") = cell.Value
    myitem("email") = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    myitem("phone") = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    items.Add myitem
    Set myitem = Nothing
    i = i + 1
Next

Sheets(2).Range("A1").Value = ConvertToJson(items, Whitespace:=2)

End Sub
```

This works fine but without going into the rest of the code, what I am trying to do is loop this so it goes down one row at a time whilst there is content there. For example first it will do A2, then A3 but if there is no content on A4 then it will stop before running the code on A4.

I think I have some code to work when looping:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer

RowCount = 0
Set sh = ActiveSheet

For Each rw In sh.Rows
    If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
Next rw

MsgBox (RowCount)
```

I'm not sure how to put this all together. I was thinking of having the loop call the other function like this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer

RowCount = 0

Set sh = ActiveSheet
For Each rw In sh.Rows

  If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
    Exit For
  End If

  RowCount = RowCount + 1

  ' Run function
  exceltojson

Next rw
```

What I am struggling with is, how do I pass this to the exceltojson function as the new row number for it to use as its `rng` value?

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting `rng` to the range you want to loop through will almost make your code do what you're looking for. Something like `Set rng = Range("A2:A10")`. Now just add the `If` statement from your second piece of code:

```
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.value2 = vbNullString Then Exit For
    Debug.Print (cell.Value)
    myitem("name") = cell.Value
    myitem("email") = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    myitem("phone") = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    items.Add myitem
    Set myitem = Nothing
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I need to run a specific bit of code per line, for example I want to push in one lines data, close the session, then push in the next line. It wont work if I try and push in the whole lot together. That's why I need to loop and increment the lines if that makes sense

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the exact difference you're getting at. You could update your question with some additional info on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I need a function to be called one one line at a time, i.e 10 times for 10 lines, but in your example it will run once covering all 10 lines if I not mistaken?

Comment: No, that `For` loop goes through each cell one by one and aborts iterating through the cells once it finds an empty cell.